# Time Difference in Dart

Tags: dart

If I try finding the difference between two sets of times i.e 07:00 and 00:30, I end up getting 06:30 instead of 17:30 as the difference which shouldn't be the case. I would therefore like to know how I can get the desired output. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String fromTime = '07:00';
  String toTime = '00:30';
  
  var difference = DateFormat('HH:mm').parse(toTime).difference(DateFormat('HH:mm').parse(fromTime));
  
  print('Difference: $difference');
}
```

Comment: Swap the values surrounding the `difference` call?

Comment: That prints -06:30

Comment: Then do: `if (difference.isNegative) difference += Duration(hours: 24);`.
You have two anonymous clock times, it's not clear why one should be considered to be on the next day from the other one. There really is -6:30 from 07:00 to 00:30 of the same day. Then you say "if the result is negative, the to-time was before the from-time, so treat is as if it was on the next day instead." Aka. 24 hours later.